# How to capitalize a French word with characters that are HTML-encoded?

Tags: c#, html

I have strings in my database that are in all-caps and I need these strings to be in title case on the client side.

I am using

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(string);
```

to do this but it doesn't work for French characters such as

```
&ecirc;
```

which is being capitalized even though it is in the middle of the word.

The result of

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(l'h&ecirc;tri&egrave;re);
```

is: L'hÊTriÈRe
and this is not what I want.

I was using regular expressions before but it did not solve this issue either. Any ideas or a general direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the result to be HTML-encoded?

Comment: I advise against saving html encoded strings in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode the html string before using ToTitleCase.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("l'h&ecirc;tri&egrave;re").ToLower());
```